# Simple question on power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $a_n$ is of unit length if it is not equal to $0$.
Can we conclude that, $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ has continuous extension on an open arc of the unit circle if and only if $F(z)$ has analytic continuation across this open arc?

Comment: What makes you think that this is a simple question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe I was obsessed with my main question, which is much more delicate. This question is simple enough to give a formulation in 3 lines though.

Comment: This already fails for the geometric series $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$. (Hint: First test all the obvious examples...)

Comment: For the sake of precision, by saying that "*$a_n$ is of unit length if it is not equal to $0$*" did you mean $$\begin{cases}|a_n|=1 &a_n\neq 0\\ |a_n|=0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\text{?}$$

Comment: @LukasGeyer Why don't you look at your own example more carefully

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Sure

Comment: @HyJu: In the example of the geometric series, $F(z) = 1/(1-z)$ extends to the open arc $A = S^1 \setminus \{ 1 \}$ without extending to the whole unit circle. What do you want me to look at more carefully?

Comment: @HyJu: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Do you mean to ask whether a continuous extension to an arc $A$ automatically gives you an analytic extension across $A$? (You said "analytic continuation after the unit circle", which I interpreted as "analytic extension across the whole unit circle".) If so, please clarify your question.

Comment: Again for the sake of precision, following the comment of @LukasGeyer, by "$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ *has a continuous extension*" do you mean $$\lim_{z\to e^{i\theta}} F(z)<\infty\quad \forall e^{i\theta}\in C(\alpha,\beta)$$ where $C(\alpha,\beta)$ is an open arc on the unit disk?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I'm sorry about that. I'm not very good at using prepositions correctly.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri In anyway, one can clarify this question by oneself in their own words.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri And my simple question is clearly represented, so you don't have to hesitate to formulate it in your own words. Thanks

Comment: @HyJu: I edited it and hopefully clarified what you mean.

Comment: It would seem like the question is to prove the following statement true or false: If $A$ is an open arc on the circle, then $F$ extends to a continuous function on $\mathbb D \cup A$ iff $F$ extends to an analytic function on an open set containing $\mathbb D \cup A.$

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thanks for your help. It looks much clear than before now!

Comment: @zhw. Yes. I have good confidence about the conclusion with a small source of examples, but doesn't know where to start off. Such series behaves nicely on such an arc in the sense of differentiation if it converges uniformly in the variable $z = re^{i\theta}$ with $0 \geq r < 1$, $\phi < \theta < \rho$ as $r \to 1$.

Comment: @zhw. This is because approaching through the line segment starting from the origin is just taking an Abel mean of a series with bounded terms and when we take two lines with small angle $\delta$ between them, the corresponding difference of values as $r \to 1$ becomes a uniformly converging series of similar series inside the unit disk.